# Storing credits in database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Just a quickey. I am developming website, where you can buy credits and spend them later for things on the website. 
My question is, is it ok to store amount of credits with user (user table, column credits and iteger amount) or it is necessary (or just better) to have separate table with user id and amount ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Both actually**.

Considering that you'll be dealing with monetary transactions to get those credits, you want to be able to get a log of all transactions (depending of the laws in your country, you will NEED this). Therefore you'll need a `credits_transactions` table.

```
user_id, transaction_id, transaction_details, transaction_delta
```

Since programmatically calculating your current credit balance will be too costly for users with a lot of transactions, you'll also need a `credit_balance` row in your user table for quick access. Use triggers to automatically update that column whenever a row is inserted from `credits_transactions` (technically, `update` and `delete` shouldn't be allowed in that table). Here's is the code for the insert trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ct_insert
AFTER INSERT ON credits_transactions
BEGIN
  UPDATE users SET credit_balance = credit_balance + NEW.transaction_delta WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
END
;;
```

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what i thought would be the most efficient way. I think that the other ideas with calculating balance from log would be terribly slow, thinking of that site goal is to have more than 100k users and guess is that they will do transactions or daily basis.

Comment: but I still have one question, you said use triggers, could you explain me a bit more about this please?

Comment: Your Trigger would work only for adding credits right ? what about spending? can be minus value in transaction_delta?

Comment: @Tom: MySQL support [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html); a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. This allows you to check the validity of data or update another table when rows are inserted/deleted/updated. You can learn more about [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) and their [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) in the MySQL Manual.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, spending would be a negative (financial debit) value in `transaction_delta`. My trigger works for both.

Comment: @Andrew Moore I dont know why but im getting syntax error:CREATE TRIGGER mpc.credits_update
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
BEGIN UPDATE users SET credits=credits+NEW.amount WHERE users.id=NEW.user END

Comment: Tom - which version of MySQL do you have? Triggers are only supported since 5.0.2.

Comment: @Stephen Orr Shouldnt be problem, my MySQL is 5.1.54, other idea?

Comment: @Tom: Is the table using InnoDB?

Comment: @Andrew Moore: Hi i dont know why but some of the tables are InnoDB and some are not, I changed it to InnoDB but still doesnt work.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN UPDATE users SET credits=credits+NEW.amount WHERE users.id=NEW.user END' at line 1

Comment: @Tom: You are missing your semi-colon after your update statement. Also, `CREATE TRIGGER mpc.credits_update AFTER INSERT ON transactions FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE users SET credits=credits+NEW.amount WHERE user.id=NEW.user; END;;`

Comment: @Andrew Moore: Still have error :( "CREATE TRIGGER mpc.credits_update AFTER INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN UPDATE users SET credits = credits + NEW.amount WHERE user.id = NEW.user;

MySQL said:  

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 "

Comment: @Andrew Moore: hi, any other idea ? I think i tried all ways and still error in syntax. Thanks for help !

Comment: Solved... i had to change deliminer to //

Comment: also it must be noted that, some(most) shared hosts dont allow Mysql Triggers, specially to keep in mind, if you are building application for end-users.

Answer (score 2):

I also have sites containing credits and found it easiest to store them in the user table, mostly because you need access to it on every page (when the user is logged in). It is only an integer so will not do much harm. I think actually creating a new table for this value might be worse perfomance wise because it needs an index aswel.

A good rule of thumb is to create a user table for the info you need on every page, and normalise the data you dont need on every page (for example adress information, descriptions etc).

Edit:
Seeing the other reactions,

If you want to have transaction logs aswel I would store them seperately as they are mainly for logging (or if the user wants to view them). Calculating them on the fly from the log is fine for smaller sites but if you really have to squeeze performance just store the actual value in the user table.

Answer (score 1):

If you store in separate table, you can keep log of changing the credits. If you store in column, you will have only the current amount of credits.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a record of Credits History Log like

- how many credit bought today.
- how many spend yesterday.
- what did you bought with credits

I think its better to put this in a separate table. In this way you can get these kind of results by applying mathematical operations.

Answer (score 1):

Credits are like money. If a user needs to purchase them, then they **are money**. Money is tracked using **accounts**. Account has associated transactions, **deposits** and **withdrawals** -- and **balance**. Search the SO or google for database and account. Here are just a few examples:

- **[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373968/database-design-calculating-the-account-balance)**
- **[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190687/best-way-to-maintain-a-customers-account-balance)**
- **[three](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a table which stores the purchases and bought credits, with user id. 
Then calculate each time based on this, it should be fast if it's indexed, this way you will be able to easily have a purchase history.